# ASP.NET: Why specific user keep getting validate error?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Most of us were able to submit request form for server decommission except one person who couldn't submit request form because of pop up alert say "Invalid User Data, return to form.".
I already double check Computer Manager in Group permission, he already have permission to submit request.

This XmlUserInfo tag role is to display and get information about user like uid, name, contact, and etc.

```
<xml id="XmlUserInfo" src="http://USMDLCDOWW002.intranet.dow.com/common/components/userinfo/UserInfoXml.asp?UserID=me"> </xml>
```

Then at the bottom of html they get specific xml tag uid(userid) and cn(contactname) to pass to javascript to verify. Here is this example,

```
 <p>
                                    Please verify the entries below before submitting your request.</p>
                                <!--<form action="<%=Application("GSDISMConfirmationPage")%>" method="POST" id="ISform" name="ISform" onsubmit="javascript: return validate();">-->
                                <form method="POST" id="ISform" name="ISform" onsubmit="javascript: return validate();">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Form_ID" id="Form_ID" value="08.01.8">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Form_Name" id="Form_Name" value="NEAt - Server Decommission">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Callback_Phone" id="Callback_Phone" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ISM_Class_ID" id="ISM_Class_ID" value="DOW42109" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="Case_Type" id="Case_Type" value="Request">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Level_1" id="Level_1" value="NEA">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Level_2" id="Level_2" value="Windows">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Level_3" id="Level_3" value="Server Decommission">
                                <input type="hidden" name="CC_List" id="CC_List" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_1" id="More_Info_Value_1" value="<% =Request.Form("txtServName") %>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Tag_1" id="More_Info_Tag_1" value="PRI_SERVER">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_2" id="More_Info_Value_2" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Tag_2" id="More_Info_Tag_2" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_3" id="More_Info_Value_3" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_4" id="More_Info_Value_4" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_5" id="More_Info_Value_5" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_6" id="More_Info_Value_6" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_7" id="More_Info_Value_7" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_8" id="More_Info_Value_8" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_9" id="More_Info_Value_9" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_10" id="More_Info_Value_10" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_11" id="More_Info_Value_11" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_12" id="More_Info_Value_12" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_13" id="More_Info_Value_13" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_14" id="More_Info_Value_14" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_15" id="More_Info_Value_15" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_16" id="More_Info_Value_16" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_17" id="More_Info_Value_17" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_18" id="More_Info_Value_18" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="More_Info_Value_19" id="More_Info_Value_19" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Needed_By_Date" id="Needed_By_Date" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Case_Notes" id="Case_Notes" value="
Server Decommission Request

Environment: <% Response.Write(Request.Form("cmbEnvironment")) %>
Server Type: <% Response.Write(Request.Form("cmbServerType")) %>
Server Name: <% Response.Write(Request.Form("txtServName")) %>
Notes and/or Special Instructions: <% Response.Write(Request.Form("txtNotes")) %>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="PreApprover_UserID" id="PreApprover_UserID" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Confirmation_String" id="Confirmation_String" value="NULL">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Display_Menu" id="Display_Menu" value="NULL">
                                <table style="display: none; border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" cellpadding="0"
                                    cellspacing="0" datasrc="#XmlUserInfo">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="hidden" datafld="cn" id="Contact_FullName" name="Contact_FullName">
                                            <input type="hidden" datafld="uid" id="Contact_ID" name="Contact_ID">
                                            <input type="hidden" datafld="telephoneNumber" name="Contact_Phone" id="Contact_Phone">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
```

Then pass Contact_FullName and Contact_ID to external JavaScript file to validate. If does not match, it will show popup message which it the problem,

```
function validate()
{
     if (ISform.Form_ID)
    { 
         if ((ISform.Contact_FullName.value == "")||(ISform.Contact_ID.value == ""))
          {
            alert("Invalid User Data, return to form.");        
            return (false);
          }
     }
    else  
     { 
         if (ISform.txtServName.value == "")
          {
            ServerValues();        
             if (ISform.txtServName.value == "")
              {
                alert("Please enter a Server Name.");    
                ISform.txtServName.focus();
                return (false); 
              }   
          }

     }
}
```

His uid and contact name are not empty because it already there on XmlUserInfo which it suppose to get his uid and cn. It work for me and other people but it doesn't work on him.

Comment: Maybe the user doesn't have access to the xml file.  You can try if that user can access the xml file directly from their computer.

Comment: The user does have access to the xml file and able to display his information. When it displayed, that mean it should be able to get his xml tag information to validate.

Answer (score 0):

May be the issue is in his/her environment? (i.e. older browser, or plugins that break application) Check with Fiddler what exactly browser sends to the server.
Another option - user's profile has some incorrect settings/values. Try to compare it with those who 100% work.

Comment: We believe it had to do his environment. He said that he updated latest browser like the rest of us and he didn't install any plugin. Still haven't got clue why he still couldn't submit form

Comment: Can you do this from his machine under your credentials?